# Fact file was parsed but returned an empty data set

Tags: ruby, puppet, facter

For my current module, I need to check if php version 5 or 7 is installed and created a fact for this. The fact file is stored in the modules directory in *facts.d/packageversion.rb* and has the following content:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require 'facter'

Facter.add(:php_version) do
  setcode do
    if File.directory? '/etc/php5'
      5
    else
      if File.directory? '/etc/php7'
        7
      else
        0
      end
    end
  end
end
```

But I can't use it in my module. In Puppet agent log, i get this error:

> Fact file /var/lib/puppet/facts.d/packageversion.rb was parsed but
>   returned an empty data set

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`facts.d` is the module directory for external facts. You could place this file into the external facts directory, but the expected output would need to be key-value pairs. This is not happening, so Puppet is not finding a data set for the fact. https://docs.puppet.com/facter/3.6/custom_facts.html#executable-facts-----unix

You have written this fact as a custom fact and not an external fact. Therefore, it needs to be placed inside the `lib/facter` directory in your module instead. Then it will function correctly. I notice this important information seems to have been removed from the latest Facter documentation, which probably lends to your confusion.

Also, consider using an `elsif` in your code for clarity and optimization:

```
if File.directory? '/etc/php5'
  5
elsif File.directory? '/etc/php7'
  7
else
  0
end
```

Comment: Using this logic, if you have both installed it only reports 5

Comment: Perfect, thank you! Didn't know that it's in the wrong directory.

Answer (score 1):

What Matt Schuchard said.

Also, you might consider that the Approved Vox Populi Puppet module uses [this](https://github.com/voxpupuli/puppet-php/blob/master/lib/facter/phpversion.rb) code for PHP version:

```
Facter.add(:phpversion) do
  setcode do
    output = Facter::Util::Resolution.exec('php -v')

    unless output.nil?
      output.split("\n").first.split(' ').
        select { |x| x =~ %r{^(?:(\d+)\.)(?:(\d+)\.)?(\*|\d+)} }.first
    end
  end
end
```

Note that `Facter::Util::Resolution.exec` is deprecated in favour of `Facter::Core::Execution.exec`.

Aside from that, you might consider this a better way of getting the PHP version.

Comment: Yeah I was about to say that I thought `Facter::Util::Resolution` was deprecated. Looks like the module needs an update.